# Which of the ruby implementations is at the moment able to generate crossplatform executables? (and more)

Tags: ruby, user-interface, multiplatform

I saw other questions on this topic but they are quite old and i also i'd like to broaden the topic:

0) Is there a IronRuby implementation that can generate multiplatform executables?

1) If not, is there ANY ruby implementation which could do this?

2) If i can't use .Net Ironruby, which other environment/tool could i consider which would provide a cross-platform gui toolkit togheter with a visual gui design tool?

P.S. Also i tried irpack gem (which allows to pack an .exe from an IronRuby project) but Antivir claimed that the output file contained the TR/Dropper.Gen2 virus !

edit* 
irpack was not working because it needs at least IronRuby 1.1.3 but i was using a previous version. With IronRuby 1.1.3 it works and outputs a windows .exe (obviously it's still being interpreted (IronRuby bundled inside the exe?) because if you had an error in your source.rb, IronRuby will show up in console and nicely print stuff about it)

edit** Still on IronRuby exe packaging i just found this which seems to be even more complete:

https://github.com/rifraf/IronRubyEmbeddedApps/wiki
This repository shows how to create 'standalone' .Net applications written in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know much about ironruby but...

you can try qtruby (an ruby implementation of the Qt/c++ libraries), it runs flawlessly on linux(unix-like systems), MAC and Windows.

Comment: @user988591: What do you mean "which [IDE]"? What does the IDE have to do with which library you use?

Comment: Take a look http://qt.nokia.com/products/ I don't know about cross plataform but I can talk for windows&qt&MRI, I use ocrasa which creates a single .exe with everything

Comment: @jj_ you can use QTcreator and its tools, please take a look http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/